# What is the opposite to laudatory when describing an adjective?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

For instance, when I say that the word "great" is a laudatory adjective.
What would the opposite to that be in the case of a word such as "evil"?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you check a thesaurus for antonyms?

Comment: Yeah, but none of the antonyms seem to ring a bell.

Comment: OK, you should include the words you found and why they didn't work for you. This makes sure that answerers can give you the best answers possible.

Answer (score 1):

some words like can be used "derogatory, disparaging, denigratory and slighting"

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of laudatory in describing an adjective using the word evil as an example would be depreciative; probably more succinct would be pejorative.

Comment: That's the word I've been looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: 'Derogatory' is an alternative. It sounds slightly less damning to me.

Comment: [**Depreciative** is a really uncommon word.  **Deprecatory** is a lot more common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=depreciative%2Cdeprecatory&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdepreciative%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeprecatory%3B%2Cc0)